# How to mouseover on a hyperlink - Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I am using Selenium Webdriver for my project. I have already automated the code to mouse over on an image, which is done successfully. But, some how I could not mouse over a hyperlink with this code.

The code I used was

`Actions build1 = new Actions(driver);
build1.moveToElement(WebElement).build().perform();`

I also tried using

`Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement();
        Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
        mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates())`

But it is also not working out. Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by moving the cursor by 1px. The last line triggered the hover event.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
action.moveByOffset(1, 1).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("x_p_a_t_h"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
```

Comment: How is this any different to his initial `Actions build1 = new Actions(driver); build1.moveToElement(WebElement).build().perform();`?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `public void mouseOver(String)` method in the `DefaultSelenium` class. The essence of the code is as follow:

```
protected void hoverAction() {
    WebDriverBackedSelenium webDriver = some_elaborate_method_to_get_webdriver;
    webDriver.mouseOver("x_p_a_t_h");
}
```

You may also need to look into putting some sort of wait time on your hover to ensure the element gets rendered before you fail (eg. fly out menus, typically launched from links don't appear instantly).

Comment: @SudharsanSrinivasan Perhaps you need to ensure the element is loaded. In my implementation (and we've done quite an elaborate extension of WebDriver to get a Singleton instance) we use the hoverAction only once the element has been loaded. I've not had any test failures in this regard when it comes to using the FirefoxDriver..

Comment: Yes the element is loaded. I am able to click at the hyperlink. But could not mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

All the other posters have posted all the suggestions I could come up with, and yet none seem to work.  When I get to this point, I take a step back and ask why do I need to hover over a hyperlink.  Is it just to check the alt text?  If that's the case, I would use element.getAttribute("alt") and just verify the text is what I expected.  I don't need to test the browser hover functionality.  The only other thing I could suggest is making sure your mouse cursor is not on the browser window when running your test.  That can throw off mouse overs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to get the color of the hyperlink when the mouse hovers on it. Regarding the second point, Yes. The cursor is not on the browser window when running the test.